# SCOPE_IDENTITY for multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

The below query inserts many records in a transaction. I want to fetch the newly created incremental identifier and use it in next `INSERT` statement

For a single record I can use like below

```
 SELECT @new_emp_id= SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

What about `SCOPE_IDENTITY` for multiple records? Or we can insert it into temp table and loop through it?

```
 INSERT EmployeeBenifits(EmployeeId,BenifitID,StartdateTime,EndDateTime) 

 SELECT @new_emp_id,BenifitID,GetDate(),@PassedEndDate FROM Benifits

 INSERT EmployeeBenifitDetails(EmpBenId,Desc)
 SELECT EmpBenId,'Created Details' FROM @NewlyInsertedEmplBenifits
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should have a look at the `OUTPUT` clause:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeBenefits(EmployeeId, BenefitID, StartdateTime, EndDateTime) 
   OUTPUT Inserted.EmployeeBenefitId, Inserted.EmployeeID, Inserted.BenefitID   -- or whatever you want to return here
   SELECT 
      @new_emp_id, BenefitID, GetDate(), @PassedEndDate 
  FROM 
      dbo.Benefits
```

Basically, the `OUTPUT` clause can return a result set of columns for each row that has been inserted (also works with the `DELETE` and `UPDATE` statements).

[See MSDN documentation for more details](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

You can also send the `OUTPUT` rows to a temporary table (or table variable) to be further processed later on.

Comment: So my next statement should be like `INSERT EmployeeBenifitDetails(EmpBenId,Desc) SELECT EmployeeBenefitId,'Created Details' FROM EmployeeBenefits.Inserted`?

Comment: I got, i used table variable `OUTPUT Inserted.EmployeeBenefitId INTO @EmpBenIds`. Thanks